# Water leak in roof of 2007 honda pilot

Tags: honda

I have a 2007 honda pilot and have been dealing with a water leak in the roof for over a month now. My mechanic has replaced the windshield twice, thinking that it was a bad seal. He now thinks that it might be a leak in the sunroof, specifically he thinks that it might be one of the drains from the sunroof being broken.

The water itself shows up between the driver side window and the windshield, just above the airbag compartment.

Does anyone know if this is a likely explanation? Are there other things that I should have him look at first?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any Honda experience, but on my Mitsubishi I have that exact problem.  There's a primary seal around the sunroof to keep water from getting into the sunroof recess.  There's also a drain system inside the recess to drain out water that gets past the seal.  It started leaking right where you say, and it was due to the drainage tubes being kinked/cracked and leaking.

I hope yours is easier to fix than mine.  In mine the drain tubes go into the shell of the car, between some basically inaccessible (without cutting the shell open) parts.  I ended up using the black RTV gasket maker to just seal the sunroof shut and keep water from seeping down to the drains to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Some times the sunroof drains can get plugged with leaves or some other debris and then the water starts overflowing into the car. You could try blowing compressed air through the drains and see if it fixes the problem.

I have also seen where the drain hoses have become detached and let water leak into the car. To check for that would involve pulling down the headliner.

Answer (score 1):

For first generation Honda Pilots, the common cause of roof leaks is the screw holes of the standard equipment roof rails. They should be removed, the roof and rail mounts cleaned, and then replaced using an automotive seal product such as [3M Dynatron 550 Auto Seam Sealer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005RNFBMC).

[image: Tube of 3M Dynatron 550]